# Javascript Image Rotator Problems

Tags: javascript

My code is very self explanatory. It is suppose to, after the page loads all necessary images, start looping through the same 5 images for the banner, with a 5 second delay in between. But, it doesn't do anything when the page loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
var bannerList = new Array();
bannerList[0] = "/portfolio/1.jpg"
bannerList[1] = "/portfolio/2.jpg"
bannerList[2] = "/portfolio/3.jpg"
bannerList[3] = "/portfolio/4.jpg"
bannerList[4] = "/portfolio/5.jpg"

function bannerRotator(){
    if(counter > 4){
        counter = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("slide").src = bannerList[counter];
    counter = counter + 1;
    var t=setTimeout("bannerRotator()", 2000);
}
</script>
```

Along with:

```
<body onLoad="bannerRotator();">
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Rats! XD you changed it on me.... just remove the else now and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/tMmdn/

Comment: you changed it one me again O_O

Comment: and working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vu6Be/1/

Comment: @All: Apologies, I know it's a no no to change the code after posting, but I had a few obvious errors that I didn't see prior. Sorry! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks! This is the exact code I have, so the error must be elsewhere... of course.

Comment: np :) Always glad to help if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (counter <= 4){
    var t=setTimeout("changeImage(bannerList[counter])", 5000);
    counter = counter + 1;

    if (counter > 4){
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

that, my friend, is an infinite loop and is always suspect... it will never reach 5.  the reason why it crashes (at least for me) is because it doesn't wait for the timeout to end before it loops again.  You might consider using something like this:

Also,  you can't pass parameters as a string (e.g. the "changeImage(bannerList[counter])").  You need to concatenate like so:

```
var t=setTimeout("changeImage('"+bannerList[counter]+"')", 1000);
```

Then to actually make it loop, you want to put another call to the timeout inside the changeImage function (so it does it after the time and not all five at the same time).  This will mean that both counter and bannerList need to be global.  Then with a little js monkey business you get the following version:

```
var counter = 0;
var bannerList = new Array();

function bannerRotator(){
    bannerList[0] = "portfolio/1.jpg"
    bannerList[1] = "portfolio/2.jpg"
    bannerList[2] = "portfolio/3.jpg"
    bannerList[3] = "portfolio/4.jpg"
    bannerList[4] = "portfolio/5.jpg"


    var t=setTimeout("changeImage('"+bannerList[counter]+"')", 1000);

}
function changeImage(newImgLoc){
    document.getElementById("slide").src = newImgLoc;
    setTimeout("changeImage('"+bannerList[++counter%bannerList.length]+"')", 1000);
}
```

You can see a demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M7FwU/1)

if you want to actually see images changing, you'll need to plug their absolute paths.

Comment: My fault for not taking a good look at my code before posting, see my revised solution, however, the revised solution still doesn't run. :(

Comment: @CODe see my comments on the revised question :P

Comment: Yes, in this method, every time setTimout executes, another instance of the same setTimeout is called.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` and use a simple modulo `%` to make it rotate. eg:

```
setInterval(function(){
    changeImage( bannerList[counter++ % bannerList.length]);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: oh rats... you had the same idea :P (except I increment before operation).  it's an awesome way to loop, though, isn't it. :) +1 for that alone :P

Comment: I'm more looking into why this code doesn't work the way I think it should, rather than an alternate solution, but I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `"onLoad"` to `"onload"`... see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

try

```
setTimeout("changeImage(bannerList[counter])", 5000);
```

instead of

```
var t=setTimeout("changeImage(bannerList[counter])", 5000);
```

so you output the function, now it sets it to a variable

//EDIT

`<img id="slide" src="portfolio/4.jpg">` is your output in firebug it does change the pictures in your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M7FwU/1/)

Comment: This makes no difference, since the function runs either way, the only difference is the result is stored in one and not the other, isn't that right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that doing `someElement.src = 'http://...';` doesn't do anything. It sets a property on the object `someElement` but it does not change the HTML attribute (it does for some attributes on some elements, e.g. `someLink.href =` or `someInput.name =`, but those are special cases). What you should be doing is using the `setAttribute()` method, e.g.:

```
var counter = 0;

function changeImage(newImgLoc){
  document.getElementById("slide").setAttribute('src', newImgLoc);
}
```

Comment: See my revised code, but this change did not solve the problem.